# callback missmatch error in angular with auth0

Tags: angularjs, node.js, auth0

Hi I'm using Auth0 with Nodejs and angularjs

**here is what i want to achieve**

1. I want to user to signup using auth0's lock
2. as soon as user logs in a callback should be called at my nodejs server
3. after that i will get the user information and user's JWT
4. then i will redirect user to dashboard page and store the JWT in browser

**What's the problem with Auth0's example**
1. they provide example either for angular or nodejs standalone not the combined
 
2. there is combined(client server) example but that's using jade with nodejs

**my code snipped**

Angular snipped

```
    var options = { auth: {
          redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/callback'
        , responseType: 'code'
        , params: {
          scope: 'openid name email picture'
        }
  }
}

    lockProvider.init({
      clientID: 'cUlBNhhaIblahBlahRp6Km',
      domain: 'rishabh.auth0.com',
     option:options
    });
```

node snipped

```
router.get('/callback',
  passport.authenticate('auth0', { failureRedirect: '/url-if-something-fails' }),
  function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.user);
    res.json({id_token:req.user});
  });
```

Note: I've added this callbacks in auth0
http://localhost:3000/callback
but dont know why I'm facing this error for callback error when I've mentioned my redirect URL in angular side

can anyone tell me what is the problem with my code why auth0 not redirecting me to this url http://localhost:3000/callback

[image]

and the interesting thing is when i use simple lock.js instead of angular like this

```
<script>
var options = { auth: {
          redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/callback'
        , responseType: 'code'
        , params: {
          scope: 'openid name email picture'
        }
  }
}

var lock = new Auth0Lock('clientID', 'rishabh.auth0.com',options);
lock.show();
</script>
```

then in this case my nodejs /callback route is called properly, so what I'm doing wrong with angular ?

**please help**

**Update**
this is my project structure
[image]

**full code**
https://github.com/LabN36/error

**Config.js**

```
    var Auth0Strategy = require('passport-auth0');
var passport = require('passport');


var strategy = new Auth0Strategy({
    domain:       process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN || 'rishabh.auth0.com',
    clientID:     process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID || 'cUheWwRxm7OLdHBRzlBNvfvfvfvfvhhaI1lxRp6Km',
    clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET || 'e37eIZpjgBnDMBtrYMwvffvfvfvfaU4jSqt8qylZMT9Oj1EiffLGViinWQ5AiuWi1-WBwA8v3',
    callbackURL:  process.env.AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL || 'http://localhost:3000/callback'
  }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, extraParams, profile, done) {
    // accessToken is the token to call Auth0 API (not needed in the most cases)
    // extraParams.id_token has the JSON Web Token
    // profile has all the information from the user
     console.log(extraParams.id_token);
     //save user detail with token here and return token only profile
    return done(null, extraParams.id_token);
  });

passport.use(strategy);

// you can use this section to keep a smaller payload
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

module.exports = passport;
```

**AngularApp.js**

```
    angular.module('workApp',['auth0.lock'])

.config(function($locationProvider,lockProvider){

var options = { auth: {
          // redirect:true,
         responseType: 'code',
          redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
         params: {
          scope: 'openid name email picture'
        }
  }
}

    lockProvider.init({clientID: 'cUheWwRxm7OLdHBRzlBNhhaI1lxRp6Km',domain: 'rishabh.auth0.com',
    option:options
});
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
.controller('homeCtrl',function($scope,$http,$location,$window,lock){

  $scope.login = function() {
    // window.alert("magic")
    console.log("Messed Up really")
    var vm = this;
  vm.lock = lock; 
  lock.show();
  }

}).run(function(lock){
    lock.interceptHash();

  lock.on('authenticated', function(authResult) {
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);

    lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, function(error, profile) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
    });
  });
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the screenshot the error happens because the authentication request is made with a `redirect_uri` of:

> http://localhost:3000/

and the allowed callback URL's are:

> http://localhost:3000/**callback**
>   http://35.162.118.253:3000/**callback**

Also based on the code you shared you're indeed setting the `redirectUrl` to be `http://localhost:3000/callback` so there may be something on the rest of the code that either causes that value to be overridden or not used at all.

If the `redirectUrl` is not set, Lock will use the current page so the likely culprit is that the options you set are not being used. If you still don't find the cause for this, update the question with the code associated with how Lock is shown.

---

Damn, the actual root cause was already shown in the code you initially provided, but only looking now at the full code made it possible for me to catch it...

You're calling `lockProvider.init()` with:

```
{ clientID: [?], domain: [?], option: options }
```

**when it should be called with**:

```
{ clientID: [?], domain: [?], options: options } // options instead of option
```

Comment: I've updated the code snipped and also added a github link please take a look i will be very thankful to you

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Ohh damm jesus you are life saver

Comment: one additional question i want to ask is there any why so that i can allow user to change password like enter old password and enter new password  instead of sending a email link by auth0

Comment: because in auth0 schema there is no password field

Comment: Currently there's no built-in support for directly changing the password; you either use the reset password flow support or implement your own custom way to allow a user to change their password.

Comment: can you tell me a little about how i can implement custom way so that i can get started

Comment: You would have to create your own page (UI) to collect the old and new password, submit that information to server-side logic that could first validate that the old password is valid and if so could make a call to the Auth0 Management API in order to change the user password. The most brittle step would validating if old password is valid, as there is no documented endpoint specific for this purpose. Depending on your exact situation you could use an endpoint like the resource owner to achieve this.